# Between vs. From

Tags: word-choice

Is this correct?

I was watching TV between 3 to 4 pm.

I know that saying 'I was watching TV from 3 to 4 pm' is correct. Can 'between' be used here, too?

If yes, does it make any changes in meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that saying 'I was watching TV from 3 to 4 pm' is correct. Can 'between' be used here, too?

If you use between, you should change the `to` to `and`.

The constructions are `from X to Y` and `between X and Y`.

> If yes, does it make any changes in meaning?

"between" generally doesn't include the endpoints.  So if you are asked what are the letters "between A and E", the answer would be [B C D].  But if you were asked what the letters "from A to E" were, it could mean either  [A B C D] ("up to E") or [A B C D E] or ("up to and including E").

*(Note: You could say "letters A thru E" and it would be understood to mean [A B C D E])*

If you are not counting individual things like books--but just points that have distance between them (for instance)--then whether the ends are included makes no difference.  The expressions would be the same.

Comment: Regarding "between" being exclusive instead of inclusive, I'd say that's context dependent.  When dealing with time, as in the example, it's usually inclusive.

Comment: @Toystedeth Time is generally measured as contiguous.  So "between 3 and 4 pm" in this example would be like "between 3:00pm and 4:00pm", without much regard to the exact moments of 3:00.000 and 4:00.000 *(maybe you were watching at those precise instants--not important)*.  I'd argue the same truth of *"it will take between 3 and 5 hours"*..again continuous, same meaning as from 3 to 5 hours of duration.

Answer (score 2):

Well they are slightly different, but used in very similar phrases. 
using *'between'* in a sentence/phrase like that means that you were watching TV sometime in the that time period, it could be from 3:58 to 4:00. Although it generally would imply that you actually starting at 3:00, and stopped at 4:00.

Now using *'from'* in that sentence would most of the time means you started watching at 3:00 and ended at 4:00, only time it wouldn't be like that is if your are rounding (witch people will do).

But in all of that it doesn't matter to much and it's some what personal preference.

**I** would use *'from'*.

[from definition](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=between&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#channel=fs&q=from%20definition%20)

[between definition](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=between&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#channel=fs&q=between%20definition)